# $a=v\frac{dv}{dx}$ used to find distance as a function of time from a velocity equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

Consider a particle P of mass m which experiences air resistance of magnitude mkv
where v is the speed and $k>0$ is a constant. Consider the situation where P is released
from rest and from a fixed point O and falls under gravity.

I have previously worked out: $a=dv/dt=g-kv, v=-\frac{g}{k}e^{-kt}+\frac{g}{k}$

But then it asks; Using the expression $a = v\frac{dv}{
dx}$ where x is the displacement from O determine an
expression for x in terms of t.

And I just can't work out how I need to do that. Any tips? hints?

Comment: Note that $v=-\frac{g}{k}e^{kv}+\frac{g}{k}$ is uncorrect, it should be $v=-\frac{g}{k}e^{-kt}+\frac{g}{k}$

Comment: Oh, yeah, woops thanks

Comment: It is $e^{-kt}$ not $e^{-kv}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$a=dv/dt=g-kv\implies v=-\frac{g}{k}e^{-kt}+\frac{g}{k}$$

and from $a = v\frac{dv}{dx}$

$\implies dx=\frac v a dv=\frac v {g-kv} dv\implies x=-\frac{g\log(g-kv)+kv}{k^2}+c$

and since $x(0)=v(0)=0\implies c=-\frac{g\log g}{k^2}$